# Express app not rendering my react components

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

I'm building a Express app using React. I start my server, go to localhost and I see a blank page, when I check the developer tools on chrome it shows me that my js file is plain HTML. Why is that?

This is my `server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.NODE_ENV || 3000;

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Listening to http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

This is my `app.js`:

```
var React = require('react'),
    ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var App = React.createClass({displayName: "App",
    render () {
        return (
            React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello World!!!!!")
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById('main-app'));
```

My `index.html`:

```
<body>
    <div id="main-app"></div>
</body>
<script src="public/assets/dist/javascripts/app.js"></script>
```

This is what I see on developer tools:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hy4N.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that whatever file you are requesting to your server you are always returning `index.html`.

So when you go to http://localhost:3000/ you get `index.html`

The problem is that your `index.html` then requests **`public/assets/dist/javascripts/app.js`** but you still return `index.html` as if it was `app.js`.

You need to update your route so it returns the file that was requested.

I think adding this to your `server.js` might fix it.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Instead of

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem but now I get `Cannot GET /javascripts`.